# In MySQL ,Can we copy data and table structures only, leaving things like permissions and passwords unchanged on the importing server

Tags: mysql, privileges

In MySQL, Is there a way we can refresh by only copying the data and table structures, leaving things like permissions and passwords intact and unchanged on the importing servers to get the DB refresh.

Comment: In fact thats the default, assuming you mean the MySQL user/pass info and not the Applications users and pass

Comment: MySQL user/pass info.  When I do refresh from other databases, User privileges, authentications should not be overwritten.  How to do that ?

Comment: Do you mean the MySQL accounts or the user accounts you setup in your application